# How to stop PostgreSQL TIME field from being cut to seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with TIME fields created with the script below:

```
CREATE TABLE interval
(
  id         SERIAL NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT test_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY,
  start_time TIME   NOT NULL,
  end_time   TIME   NOT NULL
);
```

When I insert a row with this script:

```
INSERT INTO interval (start_time, end_time) VALUES ('05:06:07.112233', '11:22:33.778899');
```

It finishes successfully, but milliseconds part is dropped (time fields are rounded to seconds). I'm using PostgreSQL 10. According to this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-datetime.html the resolution of TIME type is 1 microsecond.

How can I achieve that resolution and stop milliseconds part being dropped?

Comment: How do you know it's the data and not the display that's the problem?

Comment: That's a display problem of your SQL client: http://rextester.com/SAWDJ85858

Comment: You can get those microseconds back if you cast those columns to text `select start_time::text, end_time::text from interval`

Comment: Thank you guys for replies and sql-query examples! It is a display problem indeed.